# who does boto3 not print the profile_name of session?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working on troubleshooting the weirdness issue i have ever seen in my life, i created a new session with a new AWS profile to create an S3 bucket and yet the S3 bucket is created on another account, so weird i have no idea what the hell is going on

anyways i want to be able to pull the exact profile name used by boto3 but it only shows `region_name` and not the `profile_name` used

Why is this? and how can i get the profile name used?
Again i need this to troubleshoot an issue

```
$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Oct  4 2019, 18:04:20)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> session=boto3.Session(profile_name='profile1')
>>> print(session)
Session(region_name='us-west-2')
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile name of an initialized boto3 session is available in the [`profile_name` attribute](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.profile_name). So you can just print that attribute in your code:

```py
>>> import boto3
>>> session = boto3.Session(profile_name='profile1')
>>> print(session.profile_name)
profile1
```